# No thumbnail for .gif images in Umbraco

Tags: image, umbraco, media, gif

I am using Umbraco 7.5.3 and want to use .gif images in Media.

I can easily upload the images but Umbraco is unable to show any thumbnail for that image in the backoffice and also it is not getting rendered on the page as well.

Any clue?

Thanks[image: Check this screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was happening as it was a bug with ImageProcessor -v 2.4.4 and I was using this same version.

This bug got fixed in 2.4.5. If any of you have encountered the same problem, then it might help you.

[Here is the reference](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/ImageProcessor/issues/473)

Thanks